# Can't access point to point VPN from behind local server

Tags: networking, router, vpn, openvpn

My local server, which acts as both a router and gateway for my LAN, is connected to another remote server by OpenVPN on a point-to-point connection. The remote server's IP is `10.8.2.1` while the local server has `10.8.2.2`. I can access the remote server on this IP address from the local server, and vice versa (both are running Ubuntu Linux, for what it's worth).

However, from any PC behind the local server (i.e. on the LAN) I cannot access the remote server via the VPN link. E.g. running this will hang:

`ping 10.8.2.1`

(Running this works: `ping 10.8.2.2`)

The remote server's firewall is set to accept any incoming connections over the `tun0` (VPN) interface.

The local server's firewall is set to accept any forwarding connections from the LAN to the `tun0` (VPN) interface. I have tested that the packets are indeed being sent to `ACCEPT` by the local server, so they are dropped somewhere further down the chain.

What could the matter be?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. In the forwarding rule on the local server to allow (incoming) VPN connections, I had set the source IP to `10.8.2.2`. Removing this restriction resolved the issue.